# Using sql DATEADD function in java

Tags: sql, derby, date-arithmetic, dateadd

When I run queries using DATEADD it seems that the database does not recognize this function.
also when I just run `select DATEADD(Month, -3, GETDATE())` I'm getting:

```
Error code -1, SQL state 42X01: Syntax error: Encountered "<EOF>" at line 1, column 36.
```

I added the JAR file from hsqldb-2.2.9 as you can see

[image]

What am I missing here?

Comment: what is return GETDATE() function

Comment: Are you using Derby or HSQLDB? You have included both databases and the answer depends on the actual DBMS you use.

Comment: So why do you include HSQLDB as well?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Derby does not have a DATEADD function. You need to use the [JDBC function](http://db.apache.org/derby/docs/10.7/ref/rrefjdbc88908.html) `timestampadd` to achieve this:

```
select {fn TIMESTAMPADD(SQL_TSI_MONTH, -3, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP)}
from sysibm.sysdummy1
```

An alternative to using sysdummy1 is the ANSI standard `values` clause which works both in Derby and HSQLDB:

```
values ({fn TIMESTAMPADD(SQL_TSI_MONTH, -3, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP)})
```

Answer (score 1):

ADD OR SUBTRACT ONE DAY IN DERBY
select rundate, {fn TIMESTAMPADD(SQL_TSI_DAY, -1, RUNDATE)}    from tst.YOUTH

Answer (score 0):

For hsqldb:

DATEADD ( , ,  )
    DATEADD ( 'month', 3, DATE '2008-11-22' )

Try it

select DATEADD(Month, -3, '2008-11-22')

For Derby:

Derby supports the JDBC escape function TIMESTAMPADD

TIMESTAMPDIFF( interval, timestampExpression1, timestampExpression2 )

values {fn timestampadd(SQL_TSI_DAY, 1, timestamp('2010-12-31 23:59:59'))};

Comment: Derby does not have a DateAdd function

Comment: But Onca has also included Apache Derby.

Comment: This SELECT also fails. So how can I do it in derby?

Comment: @Onca: see my answer. And please clarify why you add the HSQLDB libraries if you are using Derby