# How to query data from timestamp column with delay.?

Tags: derby

I want a query to get data from a derby table with the timestamp where time value is less than two hours to current time. following query gives and error saying

`operator with a left operand type of 'TIMESTAMP' and a right operand type of 'INTEGER' is not supported.`

Query:

```
select * from NEWS WHERE NEWS_DATE < current_timestamp-2
```

Appriciate any help

Comment: See related: http://stackoverflow.com/a/12138416/193453

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is the answer,

```
select *from NEWS where {fn TIMESTAMPDIFF( SQL_TSI_MINUTE, NEWS_DATE,current_timestamp)} <120
```