# 'ADD_MONTHS' is not recognized as a function or procedure in Derby Database

Tags: sql, netbeans, derby

I created table using Derby database

```
CREATE TABLE PROJECT
(PID  INTEGER NOT NULL GENERATED ALWAYS AS IDENTITY,
PSDATE DATE,
PDURATION INTEGER,
PEDATE DATE,
PRIMARY KEY (PID)
);
```

I attempted to update end date in this project table, adding duration to start date

```
UPDATE PROJECT
SET PEDATE = ADD_MONTHS (PROJECT.PSDATE, PROJECT.PDURATION)
WHERE PID = PROJECT.PID;
```

But I am getting  below error

```
"[Exception, Error code 30,000, SQLState 42Y03] 'ADD_MONTHS' is not recognized as a function or 
 procedure.
 Line 1, column 1"
```

Thanks in advance to help me to solve this problem

[image: Image1]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Using sql DATEADD function in java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12138164/using-sql-dateadd-function-in-java)

Comment: @paulsm4 using the above link I got the answer Tks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As a update Query this works in Derby.

```
  UPDATE PROJECT 
  SET PEDATE = DATE( {fn TIMESTAMPADD(SQL_TSI_MONTH, PDURATION, PSDATE)} );
```

Answer (score 0):

you need to tag your database , in mysql you can do:

```
UPDATE PROJECT
SET PEDATE = DATEADD (PROJECT.PSDATE, interval PROJECT.PDURATION month)
WHERE PID = PROJECT.PID;
```

in postgresql :

```
UPDATE PROJECT
SET PEDATE = PROJECT.PSDATE + interval '1 month' * PROJECT.PDURATION
WHERE PID = PROJECT.PID;
```

Comment: I used derby database

Comment: @tharinduhd seems like derby doesn't support Dateadd function natively , you have to use java code , see the link in comments

Comment: @eshirvana: Please consider marking this close > duplicate, citing the link I gave.  ALSO: Here's a SQL server example (also not supported by Derby): `SELECT DATEADD(month, 2, '2017/08/25') AS DateAdd;`